# How to force rstudio/knitr/rmarkdown to use alternative pandoc binary (scholdoc)

Tags: rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

`scholdoc` (see [scholarlymarkdown.com](http://www.scholarlymarkdown.com)) is a fork of `pandoc` that has !FINALLY! easy referencing of figures/code blocks etc. build in - a central missing piece in `pandoc`.

Is there any straight forward way to force usage of `scholdoc` instead of the shipped `pandoc` binary when using `knitr`/`rmarkdown` in `rstudio`?

When I set in `.Rprofile`

```
options(
  rstudio.markdownToHTML = function(inputFile, outputFile) {
    system(
      paste(
        "~/.cabal/bin/scholdoc",
        shQuote(inputFile),
        "-o", shQuote(outputFile)))
  })
```

as indicated [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552186-Customizing-Markdown-Rendering), this seems to work, but, as it is missing all manner of command line options used by the internal `pandoc`, produces `HTML` out of the box and will lead me down a painful way of getting all the CLI options right.

After studying some `rmarkdown` code, I have also tried to set the environment variable `RSTUDIO_PANDOC` to contain the path of `scholdoc` - to no avail.

Can anyone point out an easy way to do this with up-to-date `rstudio`/`scholdoc` installations?

Comment: This isn't quite what you're looking for, but this works from command line.

RScript -e "library(knitr); knit('test.Rmd')" && scholdoc test.md -o test.html. Therefore you could invoke system(...)

Comment: I was going to suggest setting `RSTUDIO_PANDOC` as a shell variable too, based on [what I assume you looked at](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/R/pandoc.R). Can you give us some more details on why that didn't work?

Comment: The RMarkdown console in RStudio keeps reading `/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc manuscript.utf8.md ...`, while `echo $RSTUDIO_PANDOC` gives `~/.cabal/bin/sholdoc` just fine ...

Comment: `RSTUDIO_PANDOC` points to a directory, not a file. rmarkdown assumes that the name of the pandoc executable is always "pandoc". 

https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/a1c7ee2d1c92604f1b72c745819f2f272917d314/R/pandoc.R#L542

Comment: Thank you for that observation. I have set `RSTUDIO_PANDOC` to point to `~/bin` and soft-linked therein `scholdoc` --> `pandoc`. Rstudio now is really using `scholdoc`, but my next task is to overcome `rmarkdown`'s version check ... will report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this long ago an thought that for completeness sake, I'd point out, that [`bookdown`](https://bookdown.org) has stepped into the arena to provide cross referencing of figures etc. within `rmarkdown` documents.

after issuing `install.packages('bookdown')`, `RStudio` may be coerced to use it by adding the following to the `YAML` header of a document:

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
```